# The Sum of two numbers in C print "4194429PS" for every number

Tags: c

I've just begun my journey into programming with C
Am writing a very simple beginner level program to add two numbers. The program works without errors it's the output that's very weird. It outputs the number "4194429PS" no matter what number I enter as input when am running the program and sticks a minus sign in front of it when I try to do difference of two numbers

Please anyone know what could be the problem

```
int main( void ){
int integer1;
int integer2;

printf( "Enter first integer\n" );
scanf("%d", &integer1);

printf( "Enter second integer\n" );
scanf("%d", &integer1);

int sum;
sum = integer1 + integer2;
printf("the sum of two numbers is %d", sum);
```

}

Comment: Second `scanf()` as `scanf("%d", &integer2);
`

Comment: In "4194429PS" the `PS` part is the prompt string because you didn't print a new line after the sum => `printf("the sum of two numbers is %d\n", sum);`

Comment: Stupid me. Thanks so much. That thing was about to drive me crazy

Comment: See [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/995714). Read the warnings and you'll know the problem right away

Answer (score 1):

You read integer 1 twice

```
int main( void ){
int integer1;
int integer2;

printf( "Enter first integer\n" );
scanf("%d", &integer1);

printf( "Enter second integer\n" );
scanf("%d", &integer1);   <<<<<====

int sum;
sum = integer1 + integer2;
printf("the sum of two numbers is %d", sum);
```

you need

```
int main( void ){
int integer1;
int integer2;
printf( "Enter first integer\n" );
scanf("%d", &integer1);

printf( "Enter second integer\n" );
scanf("%d", &integer2); <<<<===

int sum;
sum = integer1 + integer2;
printf("the sum of two numbers is %d", sum);
```

Comment: This should just be closed as a typo.